# iOS Turn on capitalization on UIKeyBoard temporarily?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uikeyboard, capitalization

I need to manually turn caps lock on, on the keyboard.
Using `autocapitalizationType` property won't do the job. The problem is I am implementing a bullet list feature, where after the user inserts a bullet I need to turn on the capLock right away. This doesn't happen using standard autocapitalization because the first letter in my paragraph is `@"•"` rather than the text the user needs to enter.

Any way to turn capitalization on manually?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a while back and what I ended up doing was using the `UITextFieldDelegate` or `UITextViewDelegate` depending on which control you are using they both contain `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` or `textView:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` which is called every time the content of the field is changed. This allows you to change the character values automatically.

Hope this helps.

You can check out the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:

Comment: Can't use the delegate, This is a subclass of UITextView, If I use the delegate in this subclass it means the user of this library won't be able to implement the delegate methods. Plus I don't want to force capitalization, I want the user to be able to turn off caps lock before typing